# UIScrollView doesn't scroll on Xcode 6 (works on simulator)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a basic `UIScrollView` with a `UIView` inside it. I've set the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView` to (320, 800). The same being the frame of `UIView`. When I run the application on the **simulator**, everything **works fine**. When I run the same on an iPhone and iPad (both iOS7), the view doesn't scroll. Is this a Xcode 6 bug? Anyone else facing the same problem?

Short question :/

Comment: please provide source code..

Comment: That's what I said. There's absolutely no source code. All I've done is set the frame of UIView and the contentSize of UIScrollView

Comment: is it working on ios8?

Comment: On the simulator, yes. Don't have a iOS 8 test device with me.